# Faithfully flat descent of projectivity and freeness

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0038v1.pdf).

> It is proven there that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a faithfully flat morphism of rings and $M$ an $A$-module such that the $B$-module $M\otimes_A B$ is projective, then $M$ is projective.

The proof there is long a complicated. Is there a simpler one? I mean to prove $M$ projective one needs to prove $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,-)$ exact. But this is functorially isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}_B(M\otimes_A B,-)$!

Also is it true that if $M\otimes_A B$ is free, then so is $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasonable rings, one way to do this would be to use the fact that a module is projective if and only if it is locally so and thus we may assume $A$ is local with residue field $k$. Now, $M$ is projective if and only if $\operatorname{Tor}^1_A(k,M)=0$. Then one has $0=\operatorname{Tor}^1_B(k\otimes_A B, M\otimes_A B)  =\operatorname{Tor}^1_A(k,M)\otimes_A B$, since $M\otimes_A B$ is $B$ projective. Now faithful flatness proves $\operatorname{Tor}^1_A(k,M)=0$.

The last part is false in general. For example, take $A=\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$, the coordinate ring of the real sphere and let $B=A\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$. If $P$ is the tangent bundle of the real sphere, it is not free over $A$, but $P\otimes_A B$ is free. Of course, $A\to B$ is faithfully flat.

Comment: Great answer! but is the part about freeness true if you take e.g. $B$ a polynomial ring over $A$?

Comment: Yes, since you have a retraction $B\to A$.

Comment: How is that supposed to follow from the existence of a retraction? What is the keyword here. Is there are a term for $A$-Algebras whose structural morphism admit a retraction? Can you recommend me a book which deals with this?

Comment: If $P$ is of rank $n$ and $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ is a free basis for $P\otimes_A B$, then just take the images of these in $P$ under the retraction $P\otimes_A B\to P\otimes_A A=P$ to get a free basis for $P$. I am not sure there is a term for such ring homomorphisms and am not sure there are books dealing with these in detail.

Comment: The part "a module is projective if and only if it is locally so" seems nontrivial to me.